# is mathematica able to do some planar geometry plotting

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to use computer to show some planar geometry plots. I donot know what software can do this, or whether mathematica can produce such plots easily.

For example, I have the following plot to show.
Given any triangle ABC, let AD be the line bisecting angle BAC and intersecting BC at D. Let M be the midpoint of AD. Let the circle whose diameter is AB intersects CM at F.

How to produce these plots and show the relevant labeling of the points in mma? Is it easy to do? Could someone please give an example, or give some recommendation as to what software is best suited for this purposes?

Many thanks.

Comment: If you do want to use Mma for this (which is ok), here's some demonstrations to get you started: [TriangleCentroid](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TriangleCentroid/), [DistancesFromTheCentroid](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/DistancesFromTheCentroid/) and lots more on [Triangles](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/topic.html?topic=Triangles&limit=40)

Comment: There's a `PlaneGeometry` package as part of the [MathWorld packages](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/4775). This is used to generate all of the geometry figures in MathWorld. This can probably do all that you want - but will take some time to learn.

Comment: Here's a nice new demonstration showing some geometry in Mathematica. [Four Lines and Four Circumcircles](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/FourLinesAndFourCircumcircles/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought I'd show how one might approach this in Mathematica. While not the simplest thing to code, it does have flexibility. Also bear in mind that the author is fairly inept when it comes to graphics, so there might be easier and/or better ways to go about it.

```
offset[pt_, center_, eps_] := center + (1 + eps)*(pt - center);

pointfunc[{pt_List, center_List, ptname_String}, siz_, 
   eps_] := {PointSize[siz], Point[pt], 
   Inset[ptname, offset[pt, center, eps]]};

Manipulate[Module[
  {plot1, plot2, plot3, siz = .02, ab = bb - aa, bc = cc - bb, 
   ac = cc - aa, cen = (aa + bb)/2., x, y, soln, dd, mm, ff, lens, 
   pts, eps = .15},
  plot1 = ListLinePlot[{aa, bb, cc, aa}];
  plot2 = Graphics[Circle[cen, Norm[ab]/2.]];
  soln = NSolve[{Norm[ac]*({x, y} - aa).ab - 
       Norm[ab]*({x, y} - aa).ac == 
      0, ({x, y} - cc).({-1, 1}*Reverse[bc]) == 0}, {x, y}];
  dd = {x, y} /. soln[[1]];
  mm = (dd + aa)/2;
  soln = NSolve[{({x, y} - cen).({x, y} - cen) - ab.ab/4 == 
      0, ({x, y} - cc).({-1, 1}*Reverse[mm - cc]) == 0}, {x, y}];
  ff = {x, y} /. soln;
  lens = Map[Norm[# - cc] &, ff];
  ff = If[OrderedQ[lens], ff[[1]], ff[[2]]];
  pts = {{aa, cen, "A"}, {bb, cen, "B"}, {cc, cen, "C"}, {dd, cen, 
     "D"}, {ff, cen, "F"}, {mm, cen, "M"}, {cen, ff, "O"}};
  pts = Map[pointfunc[#, siz, eps] &, pts];
  plot3 = Graphics[Join[pts, {Line[{aa, dd}], Line[{cc, mm}]}]];
  Show[plot1, plot2, plot3, PlotRange -> {{-.2, 1.1}, {-.2, 1.2}}, 
   AspectRatio -> Full, Axes -> False]],
 {{aa, {0, 0}}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}, Locator},
 {{bb, {.8, .7}}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}, Locator},
 {{cc, {.1, 1}}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}, Locator}, 
 TrackedSymbols :> None]
```

Here is a screen shot.

[image]

Daniel Lichtblau
Wolfram Research

Comment: @Daniel: this is so nice. :) THanks a lot. Why the circle isn't really round? Removing `AspectRatio -> 1` did seem to help.

Comment: @Qiang Li Good question about that roundness or lack thereof. There is some way to address that but I forgot what it is. Likewise some improvements can be made to avoid "jumpiness" as one moves the locators. So this code could be polished.

Comment: @Daniel: please let me know if you find the way to address both issues. I am eager to know! Many thanks.

Comment: @Qiang Li I find that setting AspectRatio->Full gives good behavior. That might be all it takes. Code in answer is edited to reflect this change.

Comment: @Daniel: actually `AspectRatio -> Automatic` is the best i have seen so far.

Comment: @Daniel: Damn it! I just spent half an hour basically repeating this!

Comment: @Simon So why are you complaining? It took me far longer than that. (Mostly my graphics illiteracy, augmented by mistakes in the solving due to forgetting to think about what I was doing.)

Answer (score 5):

Here you have your graph done with [Geometry Expressions](http://www.geometryexpressions.com/) in two minutes.  It has many nice features, including elemental geometry calculations and an interface for exporting formulas to Mathematica.

The formula in the drawing was calculated by the program.

[image]

Free to use, $79 - $99 to be able to save.

Comment: @belisarius: it looks very nice. :)

Comment: Looks like a nice program - it's shame that there's no Linux version.

Comment: @Simon It's nice but able to do only 2D geometry. I use it a lot as laziness usually forbid me to do trigonometric calcs. The Mma and MathML export is a big plus.

Comment: @belisarius: It seems to work perfectly under [wine](http://www.winehq.org/). But I think I prefer [Geogebra](http://www.geogebra.org/).

Comment: @Simon The nicest feature of G Exp is the ability to do symbolic calculations (as the CM segment in the figure). Does Geogebra do this?

Comment: @belisarius: I'm not sure (this is the first time I've played with it). The latest version does have a built in CAS and can interact with Maxima. But I can't see how to to the calculation you want...

Answer (score 5):

Here's a very quick solution using GeoGebra to the problem you described.

[image]

It is the first time I've used GeoGebra and this took me about 20mins to make - so the program is quite well made and intuitive.
What's more, it can export to dynamic, java based, webpages. Here's the one for the problem you specified: [TriangleCircle](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1187749/StackOverflow/GeoGebra/TriangleCircle.html).

### Edit

For Mathematica demonstrations, there are lots of good examples at [Plane Geometry](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/topic.html?limit=20&topic=Plane%20Geometry). 
From [this](http://xahlee.info/SpecialPlaneCurves_dir/Intro_dir/gspCabriIntro.html) page, I found other software such as [Cabri Geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabri_Geometry) and [The Geometer's Sketchpad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Geometer's_Sketchpad).

Comment: Nice links. But I disagree about the intuitiveness of those programs ... I find Mma much more intuitive :). Although WISIWIG is sometimes welcome!

Comment: @Belisarius; Maybe you're right - I spent way more than 20mins playing with `Manipulate` trying to get the same thing, but then the geometry functions aren't part of Mathematica. Although, you should check out the PlaneGeometry package that is part of the [MathWorld packages](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/4775).

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica isn't the best software for this, although it will work out.

http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/DrawingATriangle/ has source code for a really nice triangle, and following that example you can add a bisecting line to the code.

Answer (score 2):

As already stated, Mathematica is not the best software for this.  There are several better options that you can use, depending on your exact purpose.  To generate such figures programatically, there are several languages especially adapted for such tasks.  I would recommend to try [eukleides](http://www.eukleides.org/) or [GCLC](http://www.emis.de/misc/software/gclc/).  If you have any experience with TeX/LaTeX, you may want to look at [metapost](http://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/metapost/) or [asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/), or even a LaTeX package such as [tkz-euklide](http://altermundus.fr/pages/euclide.html).

If you on the other hand prefer to create you drawings in an interactive way, there are number of programs available.  Search the web for "dynamic geometry software", you should get a number of hits.  Of those I would most recommend [geogebra](http://www.geogebra.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I thought that I should really attempt this problem in Mathematica (only once I finished did I see Daniel's solution). It took me about half an hour - which is longer than my GeoGebra solution, despite the fact that I'd never used GeoGebra before.

The code is not as fast as it could be. This is because I was too lazy to code up proper code for finding intersections of lines and circles, so I just used the slower but more general `FindInstance`.

A quite comprehensive plane geometry package can be found as part of Eric Weinstein's [MathWorld packages](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/4775).  It includes all the intersection, bisection etc... code that you could possibly want, but it would take a little bit of time to learn it all.

```
angleBisector[A_,{B_,C_}]:=Module[{ba=Norm[B-A],ca=Norm[C-A],m},
  m=A+((B-A)/ba+(C-A)/ca)]

intersect[Line[{A_,B_}],Line[{C_,D_}]]:=Module[{s,t},
  A + s(B-A)/.First@FindInstance[A + s(B-A) == C + t(D-C), {s,t}]]
intersect[Line[{A_,B_}],Circle[p0:{x0_,y0_},r_]]:=Module[{s,x,y},
  A + s(B-A)/.FindInstance[A + s(B-A) == {x,y} 
  && Norm[p0-{x,y}] == r, {s,x,y}, Reals, 2]]

Manipulate[Module[{OO,circ,tri,angB,int,mid,FF},
  OO=(AA+BB)/2;
  circ=Circle[OO,Norm[AA-BB]/2];
  tri=Line[{AA,BB,CC,AA}];
  angB=angleBisector[AA,{BB,CC}];
  int=intersect[Line[{BB,CC}],Line[{AA,angB}]];
  mid=(AA+int)/2;
  FF=intersect[Line[{CC,mid}],Circle[OO,Norm[AA-BB]/2]];
  Graphics[{PointSize[Large],Point[{OO,int,mid}],Point[FF],tri,circ,
    Line[{AA,AA+3(angB-AA)}],Line[{CC,CC+3(mid-CC)}],
    Text["A",AA,{2,-2}],Text["B",BB,{-2,-2}],Text["C",CC,{2,2}],
    Text["O",OO,{0,-2}],Text["D",int,{-2,-1}],Text["M",mid,{-2,-1}]},
    PlotRange->{{-2,2},{-2,2}}]],
  {{AA,{-1,1}},Locator},
  {{BB,{1,1}},Locator},
  {{CC,{0,-1}},Locator}]
```

[image: TriangleCircle]